# Python: Splitting up a sum with threads

Tags: python, multithreading

i have a costly calculation to do for fitting some experimental data. The fitting function is a sum over eigenmodes, each of them containing a specific surface integral. As it is rather slow if you do it the classical way i thought about threading it. I'm using python btw.

The function i want to calculate is something like

```
def fit_func(params , Mmin, Mmax):

    values = np.zeros(1000)

    for m in range(Mmin, Mmax):

        # Fancy Calculation for each mode

    # some calulation with all modes, adding them up 'values'


    return values
```

How can i split this up? I did something like

```
data1 = thread.start_new_thread(fit_func, (params,0,13)) 
data2 = thread.start_new_thread(fit_func, (params,13,25))
```

but then the sum of data1 and data2 is not the same as fitfunc(params, 0,25)...

Comment: It's pointless to do summation in different threads because they will never run in parallel (on different CPUs).

Comment: Hmm, why? I mean, the two functions are completly independent. I could as well write something like fit_func 1 for the range from 1:10 and fit_func_2 ranging from 10:20. Both give me some arrays back and i just have to add them up?

Comment: Because Python threads can never run on different CPUs due to the GIL (unless you call some C code or something that releases it, but you'd need to use something that lets you do parallelism with a C library). Check out https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing

Comment: I believe `numpy` can be at least build with multi-threading support(not sure whether the support is provided by default settings). Which means that calling numpy functions will release the GIL and allow other code to run in parallel.

Comment: Which (NumPy, SciPy,...) functions are you calling in the main body of the loop? Any way you could share a little more of the code? Depending on the answer, you might just have to install something like [Atlas or Intel MKL](http://www.janeriksolem.net/2009/10/is-your-numpy-using-right-atlas.html) since they apparently enable multithreading for _some_ NumPy instructions.

Comment: However, the use of a Python `for` loop is slow in itself. How fast does the main body execute? If you're absolutely sure NumPy doesn't already provide the function you need _without_ for loops, well, I'd recommend Cython, optionally with `prange` to do multithreading.

Answer (score 1):

Try out `multiprocessing`. This will effectively create separate Python processes using a thread-like interface. However, make sure that you profile your computation and make sure that it is the problem, not something else like IO. Starting processes is very slow, so keep them around for a while if you are planning to use them.

You can also use `numpy` for those functions. They're written in C code, so they're stupid fast. Check them both out and see what fits best. I would go for the `numpy` solution myself...

Comment: How can i approach this with numpy?

Comment: I'm quite _against_ multiprocessing at first, it can be quite hard to setup properly and there's a lot of overhead if you're not exactly sure of what you're doing. Try reading the `numpy` documentation first, one of the available functions (especially `np.sum`) could do the trick!

Comment: Now that I'm actually looking at your code, you already have numpy types already (`np.zeroes(1000)`). I don't know what your function looks like, but if it's too complicated, try using `Cython`. You have something that is CPU bound. `Cython` will help you a great deal in this regard, most likely more so than multiprocessing due to all of the overhead.

Comment: Well acatually the function always has to do some surface integrals which are rather slow. This is like a coefficient for the rest of the formula, that than is written into the np. zeros array

Answer (score 0):

use multiprocessing pool

```
import multiprocessing as mp

p = mp.Pool(10)

res = p.map(your_function, range(Mmin, Mmax))
```

Comment: I don't understand this one